# Measuring feature within a feature to the nearest feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, proximity

Is there a way in near tool to measure shortest distance of the input feature which is a point that is within the boundary of an island polygon to the nearest near feature which is also another polygon (squares) without passing to the island polygon? Attached here is an example.[image] I use ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: Near table has option number of neighbors.